# UIModalPresentationFormSheet White Corners

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I'm attempting to use UIModalPresentationFormSheet with a dark background but the corners of the view always have a little white showing.

You can see a picture [here.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/reesemclean/5584566306/)

I haven't seen this happen before. Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: See my answer in this related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965560/ios-why-do-i-have-white-rounded-corners-on-my-modal-view/18390700#18390700

Answer (score 6):

First import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" in which ViewController will show as UIModalPresentationFormSheet then override the viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.view.superview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    self.view.superview.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    self.view.superview.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: can anyone explain me whats going on ??

Comment: @Kunal, Redrawing the corner radius

Answer (score 3):

If you want the shadow you *shouldn't* clip to the superview's bounds.

This solution will *keep* the shadow visible.

```
self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 7.f;
for (CALayer *layer in self.view.superview.layer.sublayers)
    if (layer != self.view.layer)
        layer.cornerRadius = 8.f;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    SpecPopover *ctrl = [[SpecPopover alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpecPopover" bundle:nil];

     // Create a Navigation controller
     UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                         initWithRootViewController:ctrl];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
     navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
     navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
     navController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];        

     // show the navigation controller modally
     [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
      navController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake (200,200,400,400);
     // Following removes the white round edges from the corner.       <<<<<<<<-------------   
     navController.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
     navController.view.superview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
     navController.view.superview.layer.borderWidth = 2;
     navController.view.superview.clipsToBounds = YES;
 [navController release];
        [ctrl release];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain how your snippet works, and how it could solve the problem.