# iOS: Why do I have white, rounded corners on my modal view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a modal view popping up in my iPad app and for some reason it has white, rounded corners.

It might be worth noting I built this model view in my storyboard, not programmatically.  However, in my viewWillAppear method, I'm setting the corner radius like so...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
}
```

When I set the value above 6, the white corners become visible. How can I set the value higher without these white rounded corners showing?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Is this happening in the simulator or on a real device?

Comment: @Rickay, on the simulator. I haven't tried on a device yet, but I will tomorrow when I have access to one.

Comment: @lnafziger, yes it is. changing it, however, didn't seem to have any effect

Comment: Well, if it IS opaque, then it will not show the background through it....

Answer (score 20):

Your question is ambiguous about what kind of presentation you're using for your view controller, so I'm going to assume you're using a form sheet. The solution is to set the superview's background color to `[UIColor clearColor]` to prevent the translucent background from appearing:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Before setting `backgroundColor`:

[image: Before]

After setting `backgroundColor`:

[image: After]

Comment: Confirmed working - also in iOS 7 - damn it, if only I found this earlier...!

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
[self.view superview].layer.cornerRadius = 21.0f;
[self.view superview].layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I tried this code in viewWillAppear , viewDidAppear , viewWillLayoutSubViews , no luck  ```override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   self.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
   self.view.superview?.layer.masksToBounds = true
 }```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but it deserves an answer...

On the iPad Modal views (using UIModalPresentationFormSheet) have a default background which is a white bordered image with whitish dog eared corners. Anyway the default background will show through if your modal view background has round or transparent corners.

I spent a fair bit of time trying to figure out how to have my background view show without having the default background show. The trick is to make the superview smaller than your view:

```
vc.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
vc.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(vc.view.superview.bounds.origin.x, vc.view.superview.bounds.origin.y, 300, 480);
```

NOTES: the vc is the view you are presenting. Don't make the view too small or else your touch event will not work.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. Try `self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;` too if that works. You'll probably lose your view's shadows though.

Come to think of it, that white thing probably comes from the view below your navigation bar.

Comment: thanks, eruainon, tho the bottom corners have the white corners as well. also, i tried using the line of code you provided, but the corners are still white and visible. strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try in app delegate: `[[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Comment: can you post a representation of your view hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm my case the white stuff are hidden in the drop shadow's view at layer background color.
Solved by changing the background to clear color:

```
//Monotouch code
View.Superview.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
```

If it's doesn't get rid of the white corner keep searching, remember to check out some properties of the View, SuperView and BackgroundViews:

- Background color
- Layer's background color
- Layer's Border width and color
- Heading
- Clip to bounds

Note: DropShadow is visible as View's SuperView at `ViewWillApper`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @PeterPurple's answer, but it took me some time to come up with code that actually worked.  My example displays a modal view that is centered horizontally, but put more toward the top of the screen so the view doesn't obstruct the keyboard.  Of course I could just move the view up when the keyboard shows, but I'm lazy.  Anyhow, here's how I did it.

I created a custom modal segue and in that segue I overrode the perform: method as so:

```
@implementation CustomSegue

static const CGFloat TOP_MARGIN = 40;
static const CGFloat SUPER_VIEW_GAP = 10;

- (void)perform {
    UIView *destView = [self.destinationViewController view];

    [self.destinationViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
    [self.destinationViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:YES completion:nil];

    CGFloat x, y, width, height, yCenter;
    CGSize contentSize = [self.destinationViewController contentSizeForViewInPopover];

    x = destView.superview.frame.origin.x;
    y = destView.superview.frame.origin.y;
    width = contentSize.width;
    height = contentSize.height;
    yCenter = (height / 2.0) + TOP_MARGIN;

    destView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(x + SUPER_VIEW_GAP, y + SUPER_VIEW_GAP, width - (SUPER_VIEW_GAP * 2), height - (SUPER_VIEW_GAP * 2));
    destView.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    destView.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    destView.superview.center = CGPointMake([[self.sourceViewController view] center].x, yCenter);
    destView.frame = CGRectMake(-SUPER_VIEW_GAP, -SUPER_VIEW_GAP, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the modal view transparent and make the transparency happen before the view appeared was to move self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] from viewDidAppear to the following:

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

  self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a popoverpresentationcontroller to show your view controller, try setting the backgroundcolor of the popoverpresentationcontroller to clear

```
    examplePopUpController = exampleViewController.popoverPresentationController!
    examplePopUpController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```